# Pivot wider produces nested object

Tags: r, dataframe, tidyverse, tidyr

This is regarding latest `tidyr` release. I am trying `pivot_wider` & `pivot_longer` function from `library(tidyr)` (Update 1.0.0)

I was trying to obtain normal iris dataset when I run below but instead I get nested sort of 3X5 dimension tibble, not sure whats happening (I read https://tidyr.tidyverse.org/articles/pivot.html) but still not sure how to avoid this

```
library(tidyr)
iris %>% pivot_longer(-Species,values_to = "count") %>% 
pivot_wider(names_from = name, values_from = count)
```

Expected Output: Normal Iris dataset (150 X 5 dimension)

Edit: I read below that if I wrap around unnest() I get expected output. I am not able to understand why to unnest it when we did not nest it anywhere. Any basic help would be appreciated. Want to understand the concept of what went wrong.

Answer (score 7):

As I learnt from Akrun & other helpful friends & post 
(Not a bug or anything)

spread(., name, count) throws an error because we have multiple rows for each species x name. pivot_wider does a better job by providing a list-columns instead. If we add unique ID to each row then it works fine.

```
library(tidyverse)

iris %>%
  rowid_to_column() %>% 
  pivot_longer(-c(rowid, Species), values_to = "count") %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = name, values_from = count) %>% 
  select(-rowid)
```

Comment: Special thanks to @Akrun for helping me figure this out, Not sure why you deleted incredibly helpful answer of yours

Comment: i just checked your profile.  Great answers!  Keep up the good work!

Answer (score 4):

`pivot_wider()`, unlike `nest()`, allows us to aggregate multiple values when the rows are not given a unique identifier.

The default is to use `list` to aggregate and to be verbose about it.

To expand the output we could use `unnest()` as already suggested but it's more idiomatic to use `unchop()` because we're not trying to expand a horizontal dimensionality in the nested values.

So to sum it all up to get back your initial data (except it'll be a tibble) you can do:

```r
library(tidyr)
iris %>% 
  pivot_longer(-Species,values_to = "count") %>% 
  print() %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = name, 
              values_from = count, 
              values_fn = list(count=list)) %>%
  print() %>%
  unchop(everything()) %>%
  print() %>%
  all.equal(iris)
#> # A tibble: 600 x 3
#>    Species name         count
#>    <fct>   <chr>        <dbl>
#>  1 setosa  Sepal.Length   5.1
#>  2 setosa  Sepal.Width    3.5
#>  3 setosa  Petal.Length   1.4
#>  4 setosa  Petal.Width    0.2
#>  5 setosa  Sepal.Length   4.9
#>  6 setosa  Sepal.Width    3  
#>  7 setosa  Petal.Length   1.4
#>  8 setosa  Petal.Width    0.2
#>  9 setosa  Sepal.Length   4.7
#> 10 setosa  Sepal.Width    3.2
#> # ... with 590 more rows
#> # A tibble: 3 x 5
#>   Species    Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width
#>   <fct>       <list<dbl>> <list<dbl>>  <list<dbl>> <list<dbl>>
#> 1 setosa             [50]        [50]         [50]        [50]
#> 2 versicolor         [50]        [50]         [50]        [50]
#> 3 virginica          [50]        [50]         [50]        [50]
#> # A tibble: 150 x 5
#>    Species Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width
#>    <fct>          <dbl>       <dbl>        <dbl>       <dbl>
#>  1 setosa           5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2
#>  2 setosa           4.9         3            1.4         0.2
#>  3 setosa           4.7         3.2          1.3         0.2
#>  4 setosa           4.6         3.1          1.5         0.2
#>  5 setosa           5           3.6          1.4         0.2
#>  6 setosa           5.4         3.9          1.7         0.4
#>  7 setosa           4.6         3.4          1.4         0.3
#>  8 setosa           5           3.4          1.5         0.2
#>  9 setosa           4.4         2.9          1.4         0.2
#> 10 setosa           4.9         3.1          1.5         0.1
#> # ... with 140 more rows
#> [1] TRUE
```

<sup>Created on 2019-09-15 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>