# R: how does unnest function work and how to overcome incompatiable length error?

Tags: r, dataframe, unnest

I am thoruoghly researching this question on SO from the very morning. Original dataset has more than 1000 rows. **My global goal is to extract particular columns to run an OLS-regression**.

I selected the columns I need and transformed it to a wide format using `pivot_wider`. In the transformed table I have 5 columns which represent indicators name. The rows are respondets' ids, the values are answers.

The problem is that after the transformation the values mutated into the nested objects. I tried to resolve this issue on a sample dataset using `unnest(cols = everything())`. And it works fine:

```
examp_df <- tibble(
  seance = rep(1:5, each = 5),
  ind = rep(inds, 5),
  ind_name = rep(inds_name, 5),
  answer = list(rep(rnorm(5, 0.7, 1), 5))
)

examp_df_wide <- examp_df %>%
  pivot_wider(id_cols = seance,
              names_from = ind_name,
              values_from = answer) 


exmap_df_wide <- examp_df_wide %>%
  unnest(cols = everything())
```

But when I try it on my original dataset, I receive an error about incompatiability of length. And then I do not understand how `unnest` works.

Here's [the dataset](https://github.com/kgguliev/help/blob/main/sample_data) which I have problems with. How can I unnest the data?

#### The list of sources that I have researched:

1. [Pivot wider produces nested object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57937949/pivot-wider-produces-nested-object)
2. [R: Error: Incompatible lengths when using unnest in dplyr](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64017695/r-error-incompatible-lengths-when-using-unnest-in-dplyr)
3. [Unnest or unchop dataframe containing lists of different lengths](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59192648/unnest-or-unchop-dataframe-containing-lists-of-different-lengths)
4. https://tidyr.tidyverse.org/articles/nest.html

Original data is [here](https://github.com/kgguliev/help/blob/main/original.xlsx).

The code fot the original data is the following:

```
data_all <- data_all %>%
  pivot_wider(id_cols = seance_id,
              names_from = ind_name,
              values_from = criteria_answ)
> data_all <- data_all %>%
+   unnest(cols = everything())
Error: Incompatible lengths: 4, 5.
Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.
```

Comment: I assume that I cannot correctly unnest the data beacause not all values are the nested objects. But I might be mistaken.

Comment: Could you post the original long data and the code you used on the original long data that produced the wide data with the nested lists?

Comment: @DaveArmstrong Sure, I have provided in the post.

Answer (score 1):

If you want an unnested dataframe you can do :

```
library(tidyr)

pivot_wider(data_all, names_from = ind_name, values_from = criteria_answ)

# A tibble: 3,930 x 7
#   seance_id criteria name2 name1 name3 name5 name4
#   <chr>     <chr>    <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr>
# 1 3133688   ind3_2   7     NA    NA    NA    NA   
# 2 3133688   ind4_2   6     NA    NA    NA    NA   
# 3 3133688   ind3_3   NA    7     NA    NA    NA   
# 4 3133688   ind3_4   NA    NA    7     NA    NA   
# 5 3133688   ind4_3   NA    6     NA    NA    NA   
# 6 3133688   ind4_4   NA    NA    6     NA    NA   
# 7 3133688   nps      NA    NA    NA    5     NA   
# 8 3145092   ind1_1   NA    NA    NA    NA    5    
# 9 3145092   ind1_2   4     NA    NA    NA    NA   
#10 3145092   ind1_3   NA    5     NA    NA    NA   
# … with 3,920 more rows
```

If you want the output where every `seance_id` is in 1 row you need to think how will you show those values that have more than 1 value in a column for a `seance_id`? For example, if you look at the above output `seance_id = 3133688` has two values in `name2` column. To collapse `3133688` into one row how will you combine these values? Do you want to take their `sum`, `mean` or combine them as one comma separated value. You can use `values_fn` argument in `pivot_wider` and pass a function to apply. For example, with `toString` :

```
pivot_wider(data_all, id_cols = seance_id, names_from = ind_name,
            values_from = criteria_answ, values_fn = toString)

# A tibble: 422 x 6
#   seance_id name2         name1           name3         name5 name4        
#   <chr>     <chr>         <chr>           <chr>         <chr> <chr>        
# 1 3133688   7, 6          7, 6            7, 6          5     NA           
# 2 3145092   4, 5, 5, 8    5, 5, 5, 9      5, 5, 6, 7    3     5, 6, 5, 8   
# 3 3143656   10            10              10            10    10           
# 4 3145088   9, 9, 9       10, 8, 8        9, 10, 7      8     9, 10, 10    
# 5 3145117   6, 4, 7       7, 6, 9         7, 6, 9       6     8, 8, 9      
# 6 3148589   10, 10, 7     10, 10, 5       8, 9, 5       9     10, 10, 7    
# 7 3135731   10, 9, 7      9, 8, 6         8, 8, 8       8     10, 9, 7     
# 8 3145111   7, 7, 7, 8, 9 10, 10, 9, 8, 9 9, 7, 7, 8, 9 4     9, 7, 9, 8, 9
# 9 3149981   8, 8, 8, 8    8, 8, 8, 9      8, 8, 8, 8    9     9, 8, 8, 9   
#10 3150048   9             10              10            10    9            
# … with 412 more rows
```

Comment: I just wanted to unnest the data to run a regression, but with this data structure it seems impossible. Still, thank you for your answer.